# what are the different parameters based on which @unique in Lotus Notes returns a unique value.?

Tags: lotus-notes, formula, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula

what are the different parameters based on which @unique in Lotus Notes returns a unique value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect when it says that @Unique() returns a "random, unique text value".  It is not random, and in fact there is no random component of the value.  It is not guaranteed to be unique.

The return value of @Unique is based on the username and the date/time.  The first four characters are: First letter of first name + First letter of last name + Second letter of last name + Last letter of last name.  The final six characters are a date/time stamp with a resolution of 1 second.  I do not know how the encoding for that works.  This value will always increase with time.

Comment: The way I phrase it is the it returns "A value with a reasonable probability of being unique in real world applications." The encoding for the last six characters is seeded based on time and the user's or server's public key, So two users with similar names will generate significantly different values when they run at the same time.

Comment: @Newbs I've never seen any hint of a relationship to the user's public key.  In a test I just performed on a local database, using a simple form with an editable field with default formula AtUnique, I got RSCZ-8VMMSD with my one of my Richard Schwartz ids, and then EADE-8VMMT6 with an administrative id, and then I went back to my primary ID (Richard Schwartz with a different OU and O) and I got RSCZ-8VMMVP.  Only the last two characters changed across any of this, and they are increasing.  That matches my experience from a variety of applications that I've built over the years, as well.

Comment: you would know the internals far better than I. I recall testing it about 20 years ago when we first built relational like behaviors into Notes apps using only At Formulas. My memory (subject to significant aging and abuse) is that back then the sequence number was different for different users when run at the same time. That no longer seems to be the case per your tests which I have confirmed. Wonder if it changed when At Formulas were rewritten? 

One good piece of news is that the SSJS implementation seems to be a much more randomized and complex value.

Comment: Good to know that about SSJS.  If I ever get back to the Domino world for real, that will come in handy.  Hey, I just noticed above that the last three chars of the result of my test with my own primary ID were "MVP"! How's that for random? :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `@Unique` with no parameters and it will construct a unique value.

[See the documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_UNIQUE.html?resultof=%22@unique%22%20%22uniqu%22%20)

There is a slight chance that a duplicate value can be returned, if different users with similar names call this formula during the same second.  [This site](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/sequential-numbering.htm) discusses workarounds for that issue if that's important to you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers:

Multiple calls to @unique on the same machine will always return a unique answer, even if called repeatedly quicker than the time resolution would otherwise allow for. The counter will always be moved on.